# PHP Imagick - Install module using composer

Tags: php, composer-php, imagick

I'm Trying to automate the instalation of module php [Imagick].

I was able to install by command line, and the expected result was success full.

The Question is: 
is possible to put in php composer or another automation tool?
that fit in linux/windows/Mac.

[image]

Note: It's no imagick wrapper for php! It's the module to install in PHP (php.ini)

Those wrapper's doesn't have all functionalities.

Edit: PHP 7

Comment: You can't install php-extensions using composer. That would be pretty terrible, since it would allow package developers to change users systems and force people to run composer using sudo.

Comment: _"or another automation tool"_ - Unfortunately, asking for recommendations about software and tools are off-topic here on SO. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_.

Answer (score 0):

Try This composer `require calcinai/php-imagick` it may work

https://github.com/calcinai/php-imagick

Comment: Try giving an example?